# Logging in to instagram with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

im trying to login to instagram using python-requests module and is not working for me, i've tried using someone else's function, tried changing headers, w/ & w/o session,

```py
import requests

username = '*****'
password = '*****'

def login():
    s = requests.session()
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
    headers1 = {
        'Host': 'graph.instagram.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': '7515',
        'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': '****',
        'TE': 'Trailers'
    }
    data2 = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    r2 = s.post(url, headers=headers1, data=data2)

    if username in r2.content or '***' in r2.content:
        print('Welcome, '+username+'')
    else:
        print('failed')
login()

need it to login
```

Comment: what do you get ? maybe you should display answer from server to see message. Maybe there will be clue.

Comment: i do have it display
```python
    if username in r2.content or '***' in r2.content:
        print('Welcome, '+username+'')
    else:
        print('failed')
```
just says failed

Comment: first you have to use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see how this page works. You should also turn off JavaScript in browser to see if page works without JavaScript.

Comment: your `if` say sit failed but it doesn't say why. Maybe server send message that it doesn't like bots and you have to resolve reCaptcha. Or you send to wrong URL because they change something in code.

Comment: it requests the url and get the html body text, then searches for the username in the body, instagram dont have captcha.

Comment: i will repeat: this text may have useful information to resolve problem.

Comment: maybe you should use [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/)

Comment: by the way: original page uses JavaScript which sends username/pasword to different url then you use: `www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax`. And it has other fields in data.

Comment: sometimes it is good first to make `get()` to get fresh cookies and session ID.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to login with instagram:

```
    s = requests.Session()
    Grab = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    Headd = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; zh) AppleWebKit/522.13.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.2 Safari/522.13.1',
        'x-csrftoken': Grab.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken'],
        'x-instagram-ajax': '1',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    LoginData = {
        'username': user,
        'password': passw,
        'queryParams': '{}'
    }
    AccLogin = s.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', headers=Headd, data=LoginData)
    # This is how you will check if you logged in
    if AccLogin.json()['authenticated']:
```